# Python, create dataframe from data dump

Tags: python, dataframe

We pull some data from a URL.   The data comes down as one huge string, but within it is delimited into small lists / pairs.   A small sample of the data is here:

```
[{"date_of_fix ":"9\/4\/2023","fix_description":"Broken report links\r","issue_no ":"1788"},{"date_of_fix ":"8\/30\/2023","fix_description":"Icon on password fields","issue_no ":"1769"},{"date_of_fix ":"8\/21\/2023","fix_description":"Add Tracking to Quote Page\r","issue_no ":"1744"}]
```

Would like to convert this to a dataframe, so I can later insert it into Oracle.   But it is coming down as one huge delimited string, so not sure how to loop / split / convert / append this onto a dataframe.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: if that thing is called `data`, you can literally do `pd.Dataframe(data)`

Comment: `pandas.read_json("<long text string of json>")`

Comment: @JonSG I get `ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>` using that ? Oh ! is that meant for the raw long thing, not the thing in the question?

Comment: Oh, so you already cast it from a string to a list of dictionaries perhaps with `response.json()`? In that case, `pandas.DataFrame(data)` as @Mark suggested.

Comment: @JonSG unclear if OP has forgotten to quoting the long string or they have processed it hey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting such string with three items in each, you can use pandas read_json() function for this.

```
import pandas as pd
received_str = '[{"date_of_fix ":"9\/4\/2023","fix_description":"Broken report links\r","issue_no ":"1788"},{"date_of_fix ":"8\/30\/2023","fix_description":"Icon on password fields","issue_no ":"1769"},{"date_of_fix ":"8\/21\/2023","fix_description":"Add Tracking to Quote Page\r","issue_no ":"1744"}]'
df = pd.read_json(received_str)
```

The resulting dataframe (df) should have three columns.

Comment: A lot more simple than I had thought!!    Thanks!